# binding data type error

Tags: php, pdo

i have php script with Microsoft database.
im trying to bind `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_NVARCHAR('max')` but im getting error `Fatal error: Unknown PDO::PARAM_* constant given`

here is my code

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('insert into [feedtable]  (title,link,pubdata,description,category,image,imagelink,source) values (:title,:link,:pubdata,:description,:category,:image,:imagelink,:source)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':title',$item->title,SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_NVARCHAR('max'));
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: What if you don't tell it what kind of data you're passing it? Something like `$con->prepare('Insert QUERY values (?, ?)'); $stmt->execute(array($value1, $value2));`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.constants.php --- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626305.aspx

Comment: @chris85 im passing rss feed data.

Comment: @ Fred -ii im using pdo statment, and thank you for your link. i already have them.

Comment: What does RSS feed data have to do with it? It's still data that you need to get to your DB, right?

Comment: @chris85 if i bind with out `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_NVARCHAR('max')` data are stored in the database. but what i want to declare the data type in php.

Comment: Use `PDO::PARAM_INT` as per http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php `$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: @ Fred -ii `PDO::PARAM_INT` its for integer value. also i tried to use `PDO::PARAM_STR` and its working. but what i want is  to use only `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_NVARCHAR('max')`

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of any other help to you than I already tried. I've never used that before. I'm on UNIX.

Comment: You can not use `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_NVARCHAR('max')` on `PDO`. You will need to use `sqlsrv` drivers instead of `PDO` as @Fred-ii- pointed out in the link for Microsoft.